# An Access Form:How to get PDF of a access form

Tags: ms-access

I have a Icon of PDF in my form that i have created in Access 2010. There are 3 tabs in that form; each tab have a separate form page and PDF icon is common for all the tabs.

Now I want that whenever a user click on that icon a PDF file of that form get created.

I have written this code:

```
Private Sub cmdPrintReportPDF_Click()   
    If Form_Graphs.tab_graph.Value = 2 Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Graph_report2", acViewNormal
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report2"
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Graph_report2"

    Else    
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Graph_report", acViewNormal
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report"
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Graph_report"    

    End If    
End Sub
```

Now I wanted that whenever a user click PDF icon of the form it display the report in the PDF form.I don't want to save the report into PDF file ,just want that user can see it in PDF mode.

How can I do that?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to display a PDF without writing to the file system, and I don't think there's any way to display it within Access. You can save it to a file and use Application.FollowHyperlink to open it with your default PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Open method of Application.Documents, e.g. Application.Documents.Open "C:\mydoc.pdf".

Comment: But it is not saved in c drive,it present it my project and i want, on click of pdf icon it open that report only for view purpose?

Comment: there is not Application.Documents in vb

Comment: The Application object is in the Access Object Library, so it would not be in standard VB, but it is in VBA for Access. If the file is in the same folder as your database, you can use , e.g.  Application.Documents.Open CurrentProject.Path & "\mydoc.pdf".

Comment: not find it a suitable method there is no Application.Documents.Open in vba .i m using access 2010 vba

Comment: Application.FollowHyperlink will open any file for which there is an application registered for the file type. It's equivalent to doubleclicking the file in Windows Explorer.